# Load all content from folder

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I want to ask, is there way to load in xna all content from folder ?
For example in my content I have:
Images/hero 
Images/car
Images/tree

I want to make something like this

```
Dictionary<string,Model> models = new ...

foreach(string name in content.getNames("Images"))
{
    models[name] = content.load<Model>("Images\\" + name);
}
```

Comment: http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/xna-load-all-content-files-in-a-folder/

Answer (score 3):

There's a great [MSDN page about a useful directory access method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) and someone's asked [a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052532/xna-get-an-array-list-of-resources).

Basically, find the files that are in that directory, initialise an array of that size and then iterate through those files, loading in the resources.

Comment: It's not static, but there is a Content property on the Game class which is commonly used in XNA.

Comment: Actually the answer that you linked is an **extension method** for the `ContentManager` class. So you'd use it as `Content.LoadContent<Texture2D>("myFolder")`. The `Content` property on `Game` is simply an instance of the `ContentManager` class - you could use any instance you like. (Nothing about this has changed between XNA versions.)

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! I've deleted my false and pointless note.

Answer (score 3):

http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/sample/contentmanifestextensions

It's a tutorial about loading content at runtime.
It shows how to generate a list automatically by using the content pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily list all the files inside a folder and then load them one by one. By default  all content files are stored in a folder right beside your main application so you just need to check for the contents of that direction. You can also use a recursive function if you want to load all files from all the directories. here is a little sample:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("content\\Images");
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
{
    textures.Add(Content.load<Texture2D>(files[i].Remove(0,"Content\\".Length)));
}
```

notice that when you are asking content system to load a texture, you should drop "content" folder from file name.